# Is "입교식은 4월 초에 시작됩니다" correct?

Tags: grammar

i have to write a sentence with each new word ive found, so i want to ask if the sentence "입교식은 4월 초에 시작됩니다" correct?

at "시작됩니다" the word "시작" means "start" so im so confused. Because i think it is used for a long-term event, like 새 학기.... Please give me the answer, thank you very much !!!!

Comment: 시작 can be used when anything starts

Answer (score 2):

입교식 has the same meaning with 입학식 but 입교식 is not commonly used.

As you said, 입학식이 4월 초에 시작됩니다 is not correct because 입학식 happens just one day. But this sentence implies that 입학식 starts in April and will continue. 
If you want to use 시작됩니다, you need to put more specific information like

입학식이 4월 7일 오후 2시에 시작됩니다.

or 입학식이 4월 초에 있습니다

새 학년이 4월 초에 시작됩니다

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I agree that the sentence sounds bad.  입교식 is "school entrance *ceremony*", and (hopefully) it will last at most a few hours.  Saying that it "starts" in early April is like saying "The New Year's Day starts in early January," which is technically true, I guess, but who speaks like that?

It would be much better to say:

> 입교식은 4월 초에 열립니다.

or,

> 새 학기는 4월 초에 시작합니다.